# Why Is collapseOnSelect not working in this Navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Trying to get a Navbar to collapseOnSelect when using react bootstrap... seems to not be working?

Here are my imports...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './App.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

And Here's my Navbar...

```
 <Navbar collapseOnSelect fixed="top" bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark">
  <Navbar.Brand href="/"><img src={LifeBar} alt="logo" thumbnail style={{height: 100, marginLeft: 20}} className="logos"/></Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="ml-auto">
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/bio">Bio</Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/appearances">Appearances</Link>
    <Link className="nav-link" to="/support">Support</Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Which version of react-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.0 of react-bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use either ***"this.state for class component"*** or ***"Hooks for functional component"*** In my case, I used React Hooks.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

<Navbar expanded={expanded} fixed="top" bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark">
  <Navbar.Brand href="/"><img src={LifeBar} alt="logo" thumbnail style={{height: 100, marginLeft: 20}} className="logos"/></Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle onClick={() => setExpanded(expanded ? false : "expanded")} aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="ml-auto">
      <Nav.Link onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}><Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home</Link></Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}><Link className="nav-link" to="/bio">Bio</Link></Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}><Link className="nav-link" to="/appearances">Appearances</Link></Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}><Link className="nav-link" to="/support">Support</Link></Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked like charm.